# C++ job interview questions?

Tags: c++

I am expecting a job interview for a C++, what kind of questions should I expect?

I have been programming with C for 5 years. I know what OOP is and I have been reading about it for some time. But it is most likely I can miss important details because I do not do anything real on C++.

Best Regards,

Comment: What level position are you applying for?

Comment: It is senior position. I am confident with my experiences about S/W design with C. But Qs about C++, it would be a challenge.

Comment: You should probably be honest with the interviewer and explain that you are proficient with C, but have little experience with C++.

Comment: You are right, I will. But it is always good to be ready than being sorry.

Comment: Have you looked at the other C++ Interview questions already asked and answered?

Comment: I am checking, there are really helpful.

Comment: Thanks for making your first post to Stack Exchange Programmers.  This is pretty heavily discussed.  Please take a look at the FAQ recommendations for questions.  To prevent this site from clogging up with duplicate questions, there is a chance yours might be closed, but don't be discouraged from trying again.  If you have a specific question you think you might be asked and would like help with an answer, please ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some things I would ask about if someone claimed to be capable of answering C++ questions and was applying for a senior level position.

- Explain placement new and when you would use it
- What are templates
- What is template specialization
- Why should you make the destructor of a base class virtual
- What is RAII

This list could become exhausted but if I was interviewing I would skip over the basic questions like constructor vs. destructor or anything that was abstractly related to Object Oriented development.

If you do not know C++, especially modern C++ you have to be upfront about this. Don't try to fake your way as the interviewer would know immediately. What I find most frustrating when interviewing candidates are ones that try to claim they can develop C++ but really only know C.

This of course is not an exhaustive list of questions that could be asked during an interview. The most important ones are regarding critical thinking, designing under pressure and confidence in solutions that are presented.

Comment: Yeah, I will be honest. I will explain that I have been programming with C only but I did my homework for C++. It is the best I can do.
Thank you,

Comment: I would add what are type traits and/or policy based programming